# How to configure Unity to apply a "constant" string for a constructor parameter during RegisterType()?

Tags: .net, dependency-injection, unity-container

This is what my service contructor looks like:

```
public Service(string path)
```

and I'm configuring unity like this:

```
IUnityContainer container = new UnityContainer();
container.RegisterType<IService, Service>();
```

which of course is not correct. The path parameter needs to be specified, and I would like this to be configurable from the AppSettings so in this case I would be able to set it during configuration.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As I understand your question, you want to read the path from AppSetting and then configure your UnityContainer programatically.

This can be done like this:

```
// Get path from app.config via ConfigurationManager.AppSettings

var container = new UnityContainer();
container.RegisterType<IService, Service>(new InjectionConstructor(path));
```

Comment: Exactly what I need. As a follow up, what if I have two parameters, one that can be resolved with a RegisterInstance, and this path parameter?

Comment: In that case you should be able to use `ResolvedParameter<T>`.

Comment: If the `ResolvedParameter<T>` isn't clear to someone, it has to be passed into an injectionConstructor: `container.RegisterType<IService, Service>(new InjectionConstructor(new ResolvedParameter<T>(), path));`